# C++ instance counter

Tags: c++, template, inheritance

I have created template class to easily get the current number of instances a class has. It's threadsafe and I tried to make it as hard as possible to abuse.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>


template<typename t_derived>
struct countable
{
    friend t_derived;

    struct counter
    {
        friend countable<t_derived>;

    private:
        static std::atomic<uint32_t> s_counter;
    };

    static uint32_t instances()
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<countable<t_derived>, t_derived>::value,
                      "Trying to get count of non counted class");
        return counter::s_counter;
    }

private:
    countable()
    {
        ++counter::s_counter;
    }

    countable(const countable&)
    {
        ++counter::s_counter;
    }

    ~countable()
    {
        --counter::s_counter;
    }
};

template<typename t_derived>
std::atomic<uint32_t> countable<t_derived>::counter::s_counter(0);
```

Edit:

There seem to be some misunderstandings about this class. I'm sorry, I should've explained it a bit. Here is an example main.cpp. It requires at least C++11:

```
#include <iostream>

// paste implementation here


struct counted1 : countable<counted1>
{
    counted1()
    {
        std::cout << "counted1::counted1()\n";
    }
    ~counted1()
    {
        std::cout << "counted1::~counted1()\n";
    }
};

struct counted2 : countable<counted2>
{
    counted2()
    {
        std::cout << "counted2::counted2()\n";
    }
    ~counted2()
    {
        std::cout << "counted2::~counted2()\n";
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::cout << "counted1 [" << counted1::instances() << "]\n";
    std::cout << "counted2 [" << counted2::instances() << "]\n";

    counted1 s1;

    std::cout << "counted1 [" << counted1::instances() << "]\n";
    std::cout << "counted2 [" << counted2::instances() << "]\n";

    {
        counted1 s2;
        counted2 s3;

        std::cout << "counted1 [" << counted1::instances() << "]\n";
        std::cout << "counted2 [" << counted2::instances() << "]\n";
    }
    std::cout << "counted1 [" << counted1::instances() << "]\n";
    std::cout << "counted2 [" << counted2::instances() << "]\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Why did I make the ctors private & not protected? Simply if they were protected every class could inherit from it. Making them private & declaring the template parameter a friend enforces the correct use of the crtp pattern:

```
struct my_counted_struct : countable<some_other_struct>{};   // error!
```

This has the side effect that all actual private data (s_counter) is also exposed to the derived class, so this would be possible:

```
struct my_struct : countable<my_struct>
{
    void do_something_nasty()
    {
        countable<my_struct>::s_counter = 0;
    }
};
```

That's why the actual private data is in the inner class counter which declares countable a friend, giving it access to its private data.

Comment: Looks interesting. Please include a `main` so we can compile it and see it working. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, should've done that. I'll add an example.

Answer (score 2):

Nice use of the "Curiously Recurring Template Pattern".

The trouble with your design, is that any user of your class needs to declare their own version of the `s_counter`. Not strictly a problem but it does make it harder to use.

I would use static function variable as the counter. That way you don't actually need to declare your own version.

```
    struct counter
    {
        private:
            // Should not be used by friends.
            static std::atomic<uint32_t>& getCounterInstance() {
                static std::atomic<uint32_t>  counter = 0;
                return counter;
            }
    };
```

As `counter` is a private member of `countable`. Nobody else can see it (let alone access it). So you don't need to make `countable` a friend. Just use some standard public functions to get you accesses.

```
template<typename t_derived>
class countable
{
    struct counter
    {
        private:
            // Should not be used by friends.
            static std::atomic<uint32_t>& getCounterInstance() {
                static std::atomic<uint32_t>  counter = 0;
                return counter;
            }

       public:
            // Handy access methods:
            static void incrementCounter() {
                ++getCounterInstance();
            }
            static void decrementCounter() {
                --getCounterInstance();
            }
    };
};
```

The only person that has access to `incrementCounter()` and `decrementCounter()` are members of `countable`.

You got the default constructor and the copy constructor.

```
    countable()
    {
        ++counter::s_counter;
    }

    countable(const countable&)
    {
        ++counter::s_counter;
    }
```

But you forgot the move constructor.

```
    countable(countable&&)
    {
        counter::incrementCounter();
    }
```

Comment: There is no need for users of this class to declare their own versions of `s_counter`. Use of local static variable will only lead to some extra overhead.

Comment: @VTT If you use a static member variable it needs to be instantiated. So you must manually declare it somewhere. What overhead is there for a local static variable?

Comment: In case of OP's code `s_counter` is properly instantiated, so there is absolutely no need for uses of his class to declare their own `s_counter`. Local static variables suffer from two kinds of overhead: (1) for each local static variable a global Boolean variable is implicitly created to flag whether that local variable has been initialized; (2) access to local static variable involves check of that Boolean flag upon scope entrance. Though hopefully modern compilers should be able to optimize away all that stuff in case of 0-initialized atomic int avoiding local static is still a good idea.

Comment: @VTT Your description of how local static variables work is an assumption on implementation. Sure that is one way to do it but it is not required by the standard and there are several other ways. Also this is insignificant compared to other issues (especially when you think about branch prediction). So basically your assertions are naive at best.

Comment: @VTT sure the OP code works as long as you only include the header file in one place. Which in real life is not going to be true. So you need to change the header file and make sure the static member is instantiated exactly once. If you use the header file you will potentially have multiple instantiations which will lead to linker errors. So again I find assertions to be wrong.

Comment: No... Utilizing this header in several translation units won't lead to "multiply defined symbol" errors because it is a static variable of a *template*. In fact wrapping static variable into template was a common technique of avoiding putting definition in translation unit prior to introduction of inline variables. And no, described behavior of local static variables is *required* by the standard. Implementations may indeed vary, but overhead implied by use of local static variables should not be underestimated.

Comment: @VTT Since you know so much; then you should be able to quickly write a piece of test code that actually shows that measurable inefficiency. I will await your gist demonstrating it.

Comment: @VTT Yes the described behavior (it is only initialized once). The implementation described is your imagination.

Comment: There is really no need to write test code since you've already written it. Just compile it on some not-that-shiny compiler and compare results of optimized compilation [when local static variable is used](https://godbolt.org/g/C2j3uW) | [when local static variable is avoided](https://godbolt.org/g/ZNeuNn).

Comment: @VTT As I though. Asked to show a measurable difference. All I get is a code and the statement see the code is different. Blahhhhh. Please feel free to run the code and show that measurable difference. Your making a claim back it up with data.

Comment: Most likely you are capable of measuring an overhead added by extra check at function entrance yourself... Or may be not. This conversation makes me think that account with 70k reputation got hijacked or something.

Comment: @VTT I just know you can't show a measurable difference. Simple as that. Your claims are hyperbolic. Even with implementations that use the extra check (and not all do) your ability to measure the difference will be hidden by some many other factors. Thus effectively making the extra cost non existence. Your refusal to show actual numbers just proves your nonsense claims.

Comment: So either provide the code and numbers where you prove the extra cost. Or remove your nonsense.

Comment: The only nonsense here is your demands to give numbers proving that executing branching takes time. You should just delete your answer because every your suggestion is misleading. Including the last part: there is no need to write move constructor since presence of user-defined copy constructor will prevent compiler from emitting move constructor and any attempt to move construct `countable` class instance already results in copy constructor invocation.

Comment: @VTT Numbers prove everything. Why is it nonsense to ask for prrof? Yes branches take time, but with modern processors (since approx the 60s) we have had branch prediction. The time here is insignificant (and probably not measurable). If you think you can time a single instruction even over millions of reputations! Either prove it or delete your comments. I will be more than happy to delete mine once you have some data to show you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can now make `inline` static data members, which is designed specifically for being able to make header-only libraries without needing a CPP file just to hold the point of definitions.

Your main usability issue is the need to make a different instantiation of the template for each class you want to count.

Note that your counter can be a member as well as a base class.  So don’t make it look like CRTP, because it’s not.  The template instantiation does not need to know about the derived class it is a base of.  It is just a unique label.

Here is another way to do that:

```
using counter1 = counter<struct tag1>;
```

That is, you can declare a `struct` type right in the template argument.
You can also:

```
using counter1 = counter<counter1>;
```

refer to the (incomplete) name being declared, so you don’t need yet another unique symbol name.  This is similar to your inheriting use — the class being declared is just a handy type name to use.

---

You should make sure *all* the housekeeping members are provided, as the class you put this in will only get (x) if all its members and bases do (x).  You forgot some.  So did Martin in his answer.  See [§15](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/special) for the authoritative list.

This has been taught as [“The Rule of Five”](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_five) but that neglects that any defined destructor will also kill auto-generation of move functions, so it should really be the *Rule of Six*.  Or for movie fans, *Rule of 5.1* perhaps?

---

You are making the constructors private and the intended derived class a friend?  Isn’t that what `protected` is for?

---

Another thought — if you want to avoid accidentally providing names that the derived class will inherit and step on something, you can make the accessor a free function template instead of a member function.

But what about the static counter itself?  It still has a name.  Is there a way to put that *outside* but still distinct for each instantiation?

There is indeed an easy way to do that.  Make a variable template!

```
template<typename Tag>
atomic<uint32_t> count;
```

I don’t think this is what you are looking for, though, since you want to prevent other code from manipulating the counter.  So make the template variable a class.

Actually, the template variable is just a shortcut for a static data member of a template, and now it moves inside a class like you are used to:

```
template <typename Owner>
class counters {
    static inline atomic<uint32_t> count { 0 };
    friend class count_this<Owner>;
public:
    static uint32_t get() { return count; }
};
```

Then the instrumentation class contains just the special members, *no* other members.

```
template <typename Owner>
struct count_this {
    count_this() { ++counters<Owner>::count }
      ⋮
```

Comment: I'm using C++14 so inline static members aren't available for me, but thanks for the tip. I really haven't done a good job at explaining my intentions with this class, so I edited my post. It explains the access specifiers and the use of crtp.

Answer (score 1):

- This class can be simplified: there is no need for nested `counter` class as well as for `friend` declarations if proper access specifiers are used: `private` for `s_counter` and `protected` for all the constructors / destructor.
- This class would be more flexible of counter value type was supplied as a template parameter (with default value):

```
template<typename t_derived, typename t_counter = std::atomic<std::uint32_t>>
struct countable
```

- All functions here could make use of `noexcept` specifier.
- Putting more asserts could be helpful as well, for example at destructor:

```
~countable()
{
    assert(0 < counter::s_counter);
    --counter::s_counter;
}
```

Comment: Making s_counter templated is a good idea although I think it's not really necessary. I will add noexcept, always forget these :). Since s_counter can't be modified from outside I think additional asserts are unnecessary. I also edited my post to explain the access specifiers. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: @HenrikS There is nothing preventing `s_counter` from being accidentally modified from outside or from countable destructor being called twice. So asserts are never redundant. I think it could be also a good idea to put an assert for maximum number of instances (and allow user to supply the max value).

Comment: Could you elaborate how s_counter can be modified from outside countable

Comment: @HenrikS (true story) someone accidentally overwrites bss section. Note that assertions are definitely not capable of making code completely bullet-proof, however they definitely help to detect and localize problems faster when unexpected things happen.